# Finalizando um projeto em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com algumas dúvidas quanto aos projetos criados em python.

Se eu criar um programa e precisar passar para outra pessoa, vou precisar que o outro computador tenha o python instalado e com todos as libs que eu obtive por fora?

Como faço pra deixar o programa como um executável para os outros acessarem com mais facilidade e de uma forma que não consigam fazer alterações?

Estou usando sqlite3 como database nesse programa que estou fazendo e quero saber se tem um jeito de deixar o database sem escrever por fora, apenas pelo programa.

Quero aprender python sockets e django e se alguém tiver alguma indicação, por favor, faça!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python é uma linguagem interpretada, sendo assim, ela necessita de um interpretador, cujo que vem com o pacote Python; Entretanto, há como transformar seu arquivo em um executável, independente do sistema operacional; Para tal ação existem algumas ferramentas, e posso indicar a você a que uso para os meus scripts, que é o "py2exe", que apesar do nome, tem versão compatível com Python 3. Tenho um ótimo link que o ajudará nessa tarefa:[Link para tutorial de utilização do py2exe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/)
(está em inglês mas isso é fácilmente resolvido com o tradutor que vem no Google Chrome). Ao que se refere a Socket, tem um ótimo link para te indicar:[Link do Socket](https://wiki.python.org.br/SocketBasico)
. Ao que se refere a Django tenho aqui um bom link para te indicar:[Link do Django](http://pythonclub.com.br/tutorial-django-17.html)
. Na questão do sqlite3, sim é possível, mas procure se aprofundar sobre essa biblioteca por meio de estudos, assim saberá lidar com a mesma melhor.

Espero ter ajudado!
Grande abraço Thomas!